# Find all users with a 'Primary SMTP address' that ends with '@example.com'

Tags: powershell

We have some groups and/or users that have the wrong Primary SMTP address.

1. Find all users with primary `uppercase` SMTP address of `*@example.com` while not including lowercase addresses.
2. Result should display users Name and Primary Email Address

Tried:

```
Get-Mailbox -Filter {recipienttypedetails -eq "SharedMailbox"} -ResultSize Unlimited |
    where-Object {($_.PrimarySMTPAddress -like "*@example.com")} |
    fl displayname,PrimarySMTPAddress
```

But this returns Users that have "No" uppercase SMTP address. I am looking for users and groups that have the wrong SMTP address but have a correct smtp address. The SMTP addresses need to be corrected.

Comment: Get-Mailbox -Filter {recipienttypedetails -eq "SharedMailbox"} -ResultSize Unlimited | where-Object {($_.PrimarySMTPAddress -like "*@sample.com")} | fl displayname,PrimarySMTPAddress

Comment: That only returned users that had no SMTP address only smtp addresses

Comment: It would be better if you "edit" your post and add: a) powershell command(s) you tried, b) problems you have encountered. Exactly as you described in comments

Comment: We just implemented the rule to block emails sent to @example.com, I found some emails in the quarantine blocked by this new policy. It happened because some of the shared mailboxes apparently are not configured with the correct reply-to address.

Answer (score 0):

What you are after is the `Get-CASMailbox` cmdlet. The `Get-Mailbox` cmdlet would work as well. They both have an overlap on some commands but `CASMailbox` is more for configuring ActiveSync and OWA.

```
Get-CASMailbox -ResultSize unlimited | 
where {$_.primarysmtpaddress -like "*@example.com.au"} | 
select name, primarysmtpaddress | 
Export-CSV C:\temp\file.csv
```

This should get you to where you need. Filter the data as required

Comment: Tried your script.  It returns users and groups but when I look at the Proxy addresses they look Ok.  SMTP:user@correctAddress.com and smtp:user@proxyAddress.com.  The problem is that some users/groups have their proxy addresses as primary SMTP.

Comment: You will need to check if their `UPN` or `Mail` is what you are looking for, you can then do `where {$_.primarysmtpaddress -ne $_.Mail}` or something similar. Depends on your circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to be working for me.

Thank you everyone for the help and education.

Sometimes it just takes a little help to find the right track.

Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
$LiveCred = Get-Credential
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://ps.outlook.com/powershell/ -Credential $LiveCred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $Session 
Connect-MsolService
Import-Module Msonline

Get-Mailbox  -ResultSize Unlimited | where-Object {($_.PrimarySMTPAddress -like "*@somecompany.com")} | fl displayname,PrimarySMTPAddress